# Site etiquette proposal: do not downvote newcomer answers unless spam or nonsense

Tags: discusión, votos-negativos, nuevos-usuarios

Suppose a newcomer, first-time participant, writes an answer that's not very strong (but shows some well-intentioned attempt to help the OP).

(A strong answer being one that gives correct information; explains not too much and not too little; answers what the OP was really trying to find out (without getting off on a tangent); provides documentation with a link and a quote, or explains using logic; if neither of those are possible, then provides examples; and if the answer doesn't necessarily hold universally, then provides a region, country or setting where it does hold.)

I'd like to suggest that it isn't good for the site to downvote or delete such an answer.  In fact, in my opinion, unless the first-time answer is frankly spammy or just total nonsense, **I don't think it should be downvoted even if the downvote is accompanied by a message that provides a welcome and an explanation of the downvote**.

[Recent example](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23503/9385)

---

*By the way, does the software allow for a message when downvoting, along the lines of the following?*

> You are downvoting this answer.  Please consider leaving a comment explaining your downvote. | Estás votando en contra de esta respuesta.  Por favor, considera si quieres dejar un comentario a manera de explicación de tu voto negativo.

Comment: In fact I think the system DOES warn you to leave a comment when downvoting if you are a low-rep user.

Comment: @Charlie - But what about the case that the hit-and-run downvoter is an established participant?

Comment: Every user here has been a low-rep user so everyone should know that. It's not the system's fault if the user has forgotten that or is just an ill-mannered user. You cannot remind that forever, as it would be a nuisance for most users that behave politely. It would be like buying a DVD and having to watch an unskippable anti-piracy ad every time before getting to the main menu: people would just stop buying DVDs.

Comment: I think a downvote and a comment can be useful. Treating posts differently depending on their owner is not making a big favor to the future readors of our questions and answers. In any case, I would go easy and add a comment and, after a while if no improvement is made, a downvote.